# Binary Tree Equals() method always returns false

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create an `Equals()` method which will check if two Binary search trees are identical.

However, when creating 2 BS Trees and calling the `Equals` method in `main`, it always returns `False`.

Please help.

**Node Class**

```
class Node<T> where T : IComparable
    {
        private T data;
        public Node<T> Left, Right;
        private int balanceFactor; 

        public Node(T item)
        {
            data = item;
            Left = null;
            Right = null;
        }
        public T Data
        {
            set { data = value; }
            get { return data; }
        }

        public int BalanceFactor
        {
            set { balanceFactor = value; }
            get { return balanceFactor; }
        }
    }
```

**BSTree Class**

```
 class BSTree<T> : BinTree<T> where T : IComparable
    {  //root declared as protected in Parent Class – Binary Tree
        public BSTree()
        {
            root = null;
        }

        public void InsertItem(T item)
        {
            insertItem(item, ref root);
        }

        private void insertItem(T item, ref Node<T> tree)
        {
            //stopping condition
            //simplet tree - what should we do?
            if (tree == null)
            {
                tree = new Node<T>(item);
            }

            else if(item.CompareTo(tree.Data) < 0)
            {
                insertItem(item, ref tree.Left);
            }

            else if (item.CompareTo(tree.Data) > 0)
            {
                insertItem(item, ref tree.Right);
            }
        }

        public bool Equals(BSTree<T> tree)
        {
            return Equals(tree,root);
        }

        private bool Equals(Node<T> root1, Node<T> root2)
        {
            if (root1 == null && root2 == null)
                return true;
            if (root1 == null || root2 == null)
            {
                return false;
            }
            if (root1.Data.CompareTo(root2.Data) != 0)
                return false;
            return Equals(root1.Left, root2.Left) && Equals(root1.Right, root2.Right);

        }
    }
```

**Main**

```
BSTree<int> firstBSTree = new BSTree<int>();
            firstBSTree.InsertItem(23);
            firstBSTree.InsertItem(12);
            firstBSTree.InsertItem(67);

            BSTree<int> secondBSTree = new BSTree<int>();
            secondBSTree.InsertItem(23);
            secondBSTree.InsertItem(12);
            secondBSTree.InsertItem(67);

            Console.WriteLine(firstBSTree.Equals(secondBSTree));
```

Comment: Implement IEquatable

Comment: What is the implementation of Equals on the node?

Comment: @Ruhrpottpatriot What do you mean?

Comment: Make your implementations generic if your class is a generic class, implement: `IComparable<T>`, `IEquatable<T>`. This way you ensure compile-time type-safety.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to compare `BSTree<T>` and `Node<T>`. It calls `bool Equals(Object? objA, Object? objB)` method of `object` class. Just pass node of tree.

```
public bool Equals(BSTree<T> tree)
    {
        return Equals(tree.root, root);
    }
```